Does the third spacial dimension exist,?
Our eyes see the World in two dimensions while we rely on our minds to create the visual perception of a third dimensional existence.
Why can't we visually experience the third dimension? Surely we can rotate a cube in our hands to see all Three dimensions. The problem with this line of thinking is believing we are visually experiencing all three dimensions. As we rotate the cube the to inspect the third dimension we fail to realize , the
section of the cube living in the third dimension changes. The third dimension
remains fixed and perfectly hidden behind the first and second dimensions. Thu marking The question,  Does the third dimension exist a  valid question. The answer is remarkably simple.
Example:
Given  our cube as an example, the values w1 h2 snd given the assumption that the
third dimension, depth is zero. We end up with an object with a volume of zero .
Thus proving the  existence of a third dimension in that, if any spacial dimension exists all four dimensions must also exist***. W * h * d * t = >0*** where t= Time

Is this intended as a question or as a statement?

I am reminded of Bomb 20.  You can really overthink the whole "what is reality thing".

The third dimension exists. We can't directly perceive it because of the way our eyes work. It is impossible in $n$ spatial dimensions to take a picture that directly encodes all $n$ dimensions - when $n=3$ you can't take a picture of more than $n-1=2$ dimensions. Of course, only perceiving two-dimensional images of the world around you doesn't allow for the perception of all three dimensions, so animal brains evolved to piece together multiple 2-dimensional images into a 3-dimensional perception.
That doesn't mean that it doesn't exist. Plenty of things exist without us directly perceiving them. In fact, gravity only allows for stable closed orbits (in the Newtonian approximation) in $n=3$ spatial dimensions, since only inverse-square forces can produce such orbits, and gravity is only inverse-square in $n=3$ spatial dimensions.

I'm  not going to downvote, but some questions don't deserve an answer. This question falls in that category.

"Plenty of things exist without us directly perceiving them" That is not true at the quantum level where the concept of existence without perception is not well-defined.

@VincentThacker is the number of spatial dimensions not well-defined in quantum physics?
